# Inconsistent startup issues

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

My computer crashed yesterday, and I was not able to start it up again until this morning. I tried yesterday for about two hours. When I pushed the power button, the fans would start up briefly, then stop. I could still hear a faint high-pitched hum, and I needed to hold the power button before I could try to turn on the computer again. I got no beep codes, even when I disconnected everything but the CPU and CPU fan.

This morning, it started up normally. I have restarted it multiple times, and it still starts up normally. Oh, and I do hear a single beep when the computer starts, so I can confirm that my motherboard speaker is working.

The previous two times my computer was off, I had the same basic issue. But after a few minutes and a few attempts to determine the problem, the computer started up normally.

Any ideas what this could be? The fact that it starts up occasionally has me a bit confused. My CPU and motherboard are 6 and 5 years old, but my PSU is only 1.

Comment: Sounds like a bad PSU, go try some basic troubleshooting (like a known-good PSU, give the system a good cleaning, etc).  As-is this is too broad IMO ('could be' lots of things causing it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly, your motherboard and staffs need a good cleanup ;)

That being said, there is a good possibility that the capacitors on your motherboard are dying. They have a set lifetime of 3~5 years depending on their internal materials, and M/B price vary quite a bit on this fact.

So, after you ensured that the PC is quite clean to move cooling air sufficiently, you should better prepared for its upcoming self-"retirement".

Comment: I have never heard of capacitors having a lifetime of five years.  The bad ones might die early, but they should last ten years or more.